# Aggregate (sum) cell values in high resolution raster that intersect low resolution raster using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I am trying to aggregate/resample values in a high spatial resolution raster (raster 1) to another lower resolution raster (raster 2).

Raster 1 contains binary yes/no values. I wish to sum these when they intersect low resolution cells of raster 2.

I have tried the ArcMap Aggregate tool but you must specify the number of times to enlarge the input raster cell, rather than specifying the output cell size. The ArcMap resample tool does not offer a sum aggregation technique. I've considered converting the raster to points but this won't represent the full spatial extent of each cell.

What other ways could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try to use the settings in the geoprocessing analysis environment, as  "Extent" and "Cell size" are recognized by the tool "Aggregate".

As the Aggregate-help says:

> To determine the output raster's resolution when an integer cell size
>   has been specified, multiply the cell resolution of the analysis
>   environment by the input cell factor parameter. If the cell size for
>   the analysis environment is set to the minimum or maximum of the
>   inputs, the resolution of the output raster will be the product of the
>   input raster's resolution multiplied by the specified cell factor.